# Can't get to the installation screen, keeps rebooting

Tags: 12.04, installation

I'm trying to install 12.04.1 and after I choose install or live, it just goes to a blinking cursor or some text, then reboots the machine.

I've tried `nomodeset`, alternate install, DVD install, and USB.  Same problem with all of them. I've also tried unplugging unnecessary devices such as my webcam and 2nd monitor.

Specification:

- Gigabyte mobo
- AMD Phenom II 965 @ 3.7Ghz
- 4GB DDR2 1066
- AMD Radeon HD 6870
- Creative Sound Blaster X-fi xtreme gamer

Answer (score -1):

There's a [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/765438) about Ubuntu booting with the laptop backlight off; that might be the problem you're seeing.

Comment: He says, he can't even install Ubuntu. How can he get the grub menu?

Comment: That is correct.  I can't.

Comment: It's a desktop and the backlight doesn't go off, because there's a blinking cursor before it reboots.